# Where to post my question about AWS use

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I posted a question [Amazon Mechanical Turk Command Line Tools - A JNI error has occurred](https://superuser.com/questions/1398835/amazon-mechanical-turk-command-line-tools-a-jni-error-has-occurred) on SuperUser based on this StackExchange Meta question [Best Stack Exchange site for asking about Amazon AWS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141942/best-stack-exchange-site-for-asking-about-amazon-aws) that said questions about setting up AWS for personal use belong on SuperUser.  However it was put on hold as off-topic.

Is there somewhere better for questions of this sort?

Comment: I would say [SF]

Comment: It was closed not because it’s a AWS question but due the fact it’s a question about a Java exception

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079556/getbalance-sh-on-amazon-mechanical-turk-mturk-command-line-tools-clt-returns) might help but I also found numerous results when I searched for the exception.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not an exception coming from code I wrote, but coming from code I'm attempting to use.  It's not an SSL exception like the one you linked.  I also found several results when I searched for the exception, but nothing that I found helpful.  In any case, are you saying that it belongs on Stack Exchange where the questions you linked was?